# How to paste clipboard text in VS Code Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have updated VS Code today on my Windows 7 machine. VS Code introduced Terminal inside the VS Code.

Right-Click is disabled in Terminal. Is there any Keyboard shortcut to paste the text in VS Code?

Comment: Does the usual Ctrl+V work?

Comment: @E_net4 No it didn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got answer, [link](https://efficientuser.wordpress.com/2016/06/08/how-to-paste-clipboard-text-in-visual-studio-code-terminal-in-windows/)

Right-Click on the cursor line did the trick

[image]

Comment: currently this answer no longer works on the insiders build (and I guess all future builds), now copy and paste are by default bound to ctrl+insert and shift+insert

Comment: Yes, we can copy and paste text in terminal with keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: in mac what should I type? the cmd + v does not work

Comment: @HananShteingart - not sure.

Comment: it was shift + cmd + v

Answer (score 8):

With v1.40 you can set this :

```
"terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "paste"
```

to **always** paste into the terminal with a rightclick.   There are three other options there, including `default` (show the context menu), `copyPaste` (copy when there is a selection, otherwise paste) and `selectWord` ( select the current word and open the context menu).

Answer (score 2):

Open the settings json file by CTRL+shift+p then type **Open User Settings (JSON)**

[image]

Now add this new line:

```
"terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "paste"
```

[image]

Save changes and now you will be able to right click to paste in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was searching this in 2023 and I don't see what I think is the most appropriate answer, I'm adding this, in the default settings JSON, there are default skipped commands, which remove the ability to use specific key-bindings in the terminal, you can search for exactly what you need and add it, in my case, I ended up adding:

```
workbench.action.terminal.paste
workbench.action.terminal.pasteSelection
workbench.action.terminal.copyselection
```

to enable copy and paste with ctrl+v and ctrl+c

You can find this by searching settings for "Commands to Skip Shell"

If you want literally all keybindings to be used by the shell you can take the easier route and just search "Send Keybindings to Shell" and click the checkbox, this bypasses all of the skipped commands I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).