# Paste to vscode terminal from clipboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

is it possible copy selected text (example: browser) and paste with right click to vscode terminal? I d like to use `Integrated: Right Click Behavior` **copyPaste** from browser.

Comment: And that doesn't work for you now?

Comment: That interesting, its working from terminal where i can select text and copy with right click to vscode terminal. But  not from browser https://kapwi.ng/c/eElukcYx

Answer (score 0):

First, you have the [setting (since VSCode 1.40)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58701553/6309)

```
"terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "paste"
```

Second, with VSCode 1.47 (June 2020), that will even work in a Debug terminal ([issue 100235](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100235))

[image: paste]

The combination of the two means you can paste with a right-click.
See [PR 100288](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/100288):

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/f1cfe66ae6ad3ec7718c308c1c702d11.gif]